# Convert and reconvert a version to number to store in database

Tags: php

is there any algorithm to convert an string like `1.0.0` to a sortable number via PHP?

It should be able to convert to same string again. It's not possible to just remove dots. Also length of version is unknown, for example `1.0.0`, `11.222.0`, `0.8.1526`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on an arbitrary length there is no way to uniquely map the numbers with at the same time maintaining the ordering criterion. Maybe you just want to sort the version numbers without conversion (see other answers)?

Comment: Then it will be possible. If your version consists of three parts A.B.C where each is at most of length N (in decimal digits) you can use A*10^(2*N)+B*10^N+C as a unique version number.

Comment: could you give me a sample dear Howard ? i didn't understand what do you mean by `^` character

Comment: OK. ^ means exponentiation. As an example assume your subversion numbers have at most 3 digits, e.g. V3.109.78. Then you calculate 3*1000000 + 109*1000 + 78 = 3109078 and get a unique number (i.e. you can also calculate back from there by inserting dots at appropriate positions 3.109.078 and removing leading zeros if wanted 3.109.78).

Comment: Thank you Howard, so how to convert it to the same string ?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to sort versions, there is no need to convert.

```
<?php 
$versions = array('1.0.0', '11.222.0', '0.8.1256');
usort($versions, 'version_compare');

var_dump($versions);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "0.8.1256"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "1.0.0"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "11.222.0"
}
```

Comment: Versions are stored in database and the problem is that MySQL would not sort string numbers correctly, i thought it could be a good idea to store them as a number.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid there is no easy solution unless you fix the number of digits between each dot (like, no more than 4 digits). You can still fetch rows and sort them after, but it's not optimized if you want, for example, to select the 10 latest versions only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare versions numbers, you could just use the [**`version_compare()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function.

And if you have an array of versions that you need to sort, you could use a function such as [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/usort) / [`uasort()`](http://www.php.net/uasort), with a callback based on `version_compare()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect version segmentation with numbers like `12345` (eg. `0.9.12345.2`), then you may be best off exploding the string and storing each segment in separate field in SQL.

That way you can sort it how ever you wish.

Comment: so it's not useful in a condition like `WHERE version > '2.4.1'`

Comment: @Omid you may convert this condition into WHERE (version>2) or (version==2 and subversion>4) or (version==2 and subversion==4 and revision>=1).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = explode('.', $a);
    $b = explode('.', $b);

    $m = min(count($a), count($b));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
      if (intval($a[$i]) < intval($b[$i]))
        return -1;
      else
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: Didn't know about [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php), that might be a better option if it works as you need.

Comment: You should use `min` instead of `max`. Additionally, your algorithm returns `1` for when the version numbers are equal.

Comment: Versions are stored in database and the problem is that MySQL would not sort string numbers correctly, i thought it could be a good idea to store them as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of functions that convert version to string and vice-versa.

So you can store the strings in your database and be able to sort them. I've used a length of 5 char but you can adapt to your needs.

```
function version_to_str($version) {
    $list = explode('.', $version);
    $str = '';
    foreach ($list as $element) {
        $str .= sprintf('%05d', $element);
    }
    return $str;
}
function str_to_version($str) {
    $version = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i+=5) {
        $version[] = intval(substr($str, $i, 5));
    }
    return implode('.', $version);
}

$versions = array('1.0.0', '11.222.0', '0.8.1526');

$versions = array_map("version_to_str", $versions);
sort($versions);
$versions = array_map("str_to_version", $versions);
print_r($versions);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.8.1526
    [1] => 1.0.0
    [2] => 11.222.0
)
```